# How to escape display: -webkit-box; declaration in LESS?

Tags: css, web, webkit, less

Escaping in LESS, either through `e` or `~` works pretty well in most of the cases. However, the declaration `display: -webkit-box;` doesn't show in the resulting CSS, even after using `e` or `~`.

All other declarations of that class is present but `display: -webkit-box;`

What am I missing?

Comment: Less passes this declaration [just fine](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3A%20-webkit-box%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D) - you don't need any escaping (which is mostly necessary to pass *not-valid-CSS* statements). How do you check your `display: -webkit-box;` is there or not?

Comment: Checking that in the resulting CSS file (in the same class of course).

Comment: What Less compiler do you use? I'm not aware of any that silently may remove a rule, be it valid or not. So the problem is most likely elsewhere (for example the rule could be removed by some other tool in your CSS processing chain - if any).

Answer (score 1):

`display: -moz-box / -webkit-box`

[**Per MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex)

> This property is a non-standard extension. There was an old draft of the CSS3 Flexbox specification that defined a box-flex property, but that draft has since been superseded.

They also state:

> **Warning**: This is a property for controlling parts of the XUL box model. It does not match either the old CSS Flexible Box Layout Module drafts for 'box-flex' (which were based on this property) or the behavior of '-webkit-box-flex' (which is based on those drafts).

Basically, don't use it...it has almost no browser support (except older versions of Firefox)